# How do you create a custom login page for google apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I want to create a custom login page for the google app domain. This is for a non profit I do work for so they are on the education edition.

I've looked over the documentation and it seems there are a few solutions but as I've just recently learned python and am new to programming web services I don't quite follow all of what is mentioned on the docs.

Looking at the google apps 'Users Python API Overview' [Link to API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) it looks like what im looking for until you read the 'Signing in and out' section. It states "If the user is not signed in, the app can direct the user to Google Accounts to sign in or create a new Google account". I'd the users not to be redirected to the default google login and then come back. I'd like the custom login page to log them in instead.

How would I accomplish this custom login page? Or at least point me in the right direction if you could.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible within google itself, AFAIK.  One of the hallmarks of open authentication is that you recognize the login page.

If you want to make your own implementation you will have to use [google's SSO service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) and perform the verification on the back-end.

Unfortunately there aren't too many one-pagers on this.  There are nice libraries for PHP [here](https://github.com/openid/php-openid), and Rails.  I will have a look around to see if I can find more concise examples.  At a minimum, however, you're going to have to build a page, upload some certificates for your server and handle the presentation layer yourself.

Comment: Is this how universities sign in their students to there google app email then? They use this SSO service? How hard do you think it would be for someone who just started python/web programming to be able to create a barebones google app engine to authenticate sign in and redirect to email?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started) to get readymade forms by writing minimal markup and need no knowledge of css/javascript. All you now need is a bit of python code to integrate the form data with your app-engine backend.

Here is an example of what I've developed for an ongoing project.

[image]

**Edit on 7-Dec:**

Based on the commented discussions, I here is an example of how I handled user authentication in my GAE app:

```
class Login(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('login.html')
        user=''
        if self.session.has_key('user'):
            user = self.session['user']
        failure='n'
        if self.request.environ['PATH_INFO']=='/failure':
            failure='y'
        values={'project': project,'summary':summary,'theme':self.session['theme'],'user':user,'fail':failure}
        self.response.write( template.render(values) )

    def post(self):
        #TODO: validate user
        if self.session.get('user'):
            del self.session['user']
        temail=self.request.get('loginuser').lower()
        q=ndb.gql("select password from Will where email='" + temail + "'",ancestor=get_key())
        #~ if not q:
            #~ self.redirect('/failure')
        #~ else:
        result=q.fetch(1)
        #self.response.write("select password from Will where email='" + temail + "'")
        if len(result)>0:
            if self.request.get('loginpassword') == result[0].password:
                self.session['user'] = temail #loginpassword
                self.redirect('/')
                #logging.info('User %s just logged in' % sessions['user'])
            else:
                self.redirect('/failure') #incorrect password
        else:
            self.redirect('/failure') #username does not exist
```

In above code, BaseHandler class is a convenience class I've created by deriving from the default webapp2.RequestHandler class. See my [article](http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/how-to-handle-sessions-in-google-app-engine/) to know exactly how sessions could be handled using this method.

Within the Login class, all I do is handle a post() request and validate the email & password the user just entered using the information in the data store. The get() method simply redirects user to the login page in the screenshot above. Are you okay with this kind of authentication, or you want the user to be able to actually use his google/gmail credentials to authenticate to your site?

Comment: I can write the html and css but I don't understand know how to authenticate to google apps. Google provides documentation but the SSO protion is out of my knowledge. Is that something you could help with?

Comment: Why is it necessary for you to use google authentication? It would be much much easier if you create your custom authentication system and handle users by session. You can store the credentials in the google big datastore and optionally encrypting them for more security.

Comment: You may be absolutely right because my limited knowledge on the subject. Currently my understanding is - if you use google apps for non profits (same as google apps education) by default you can only log in at two places. Regular gmail login with username@yourdomain.com or a really cheesey login google provides: http://goo.gl/UQw7R2 (couldn't find a pic). I know apps like gcontrol (http://www.gcontrolapp.com/) or schools that use google apps have custom login pages for google apps that dont look so cheesy. So far SSO is the only thing that i've seen that allows you to do that 'I think'..

Comment: See my updated answer with a code-example of my implementation.

Comment: You asked if I wanted the user to use their gmail/google credentials and the answer is yes. Litterally all I want the users to do is go to login.somedomain.org > login at login.somedomain.org without being redirected to googles login page > be forwarded to their google email.

Comment: Possibly what im looking for is 'OAuth 2.0 for login' at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login but again I have not much clue what im doing so its slow going understanding the docs.

Comment: In that case, I can't help you as I've not done this before. Going through the docs is the only option. But if you are stuck anywhere, then do let me know, I'll do whatever I can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding to this question as it doesn't have an accepted answer and still gets a fair number of views. As per the above, a custom login page for obtaining Google credentials requires implementing a Single-Sign On identity provider. This is done through the Google Apps frontend as mentioned in '[Configuring permissions on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview)'.

Details on how this is done are outlined in the documents '[Set up Single Sign-On (SSO) for Google Apps accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en)' and '[SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) Service for Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation)'.

Answer (score -1):

After enabling SSO it becomes easy to Customize Login Page. Some ready SSO are available like [gControl](http://www.cloudcodes.com) using which Admin can easily customize Login page. Also Organization build in house SSO and through that they can get Login Page.

Comment: If I enabled SSO would all my users have to change their password and manage them myself or could I just pass credentials to google to manage?